# delphi 2009, interface already released

Tags: delphi, memory-management, interface, record

I want special record that is have interface.

and, the interface has child interface and some class. so, need auto release.
but, interface in record is already released.

need help, why reference count is missmatch ?

I try next code...

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
type
  IIn = interface
    procedure SetValue(v : string);
    function AsString() : string;
    function GetChild() : IIn;
  end;

  RIn = record
    FIn : IIn;

    procedure SetInterface(intf : IIn);
    procedure SetValue(v : string);
    function AsString() : string;
    function GetChild() : RIn;
  end;

  TIn = class(TInterfacedObject, IIn)
  private
    FChild : IIn;
    FValue : string;
  public
    procedure SetValue(v : string);
    function AsString() : string;
    function GetChild() : IIn;
  end;
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
procedure RIn.SetInterface(intf : IIn);
begin
  FIn := intf;
end;

function RIn.GetChild() : RIn;
var
  childInterface : IIn;
begin
  if FIn = nil then FIn := TIn.Create();
  childInterface := FIn.GetChild();

  Result.SetInterface( childInterface );
end;

procedure RIn.SetValue(v : string);
begin
  if FIn = nil then FIn := TIn.Create();
  FIn.SetValue(v);
end;

function RIn.AsString() : string;
begin
  if FIn = nil then FIn := TIn.Create();

  Result := FIn.AsString();
end;

function RIn.GetRefCnt() : integer;
begin
  if FIn = nil then FIn := TIn.Create();

  Result := FIn.GetRefCnt();
end;

procedure TIn.SetValue(v : string);
begin
  FValue := v;
end;

function TIn.AsString() : string;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;

function TIn.GetChild() : IIn;
begin
  if FChild = nil then FChild := TIn.Create();

  Result := FChild;
end;
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// global var
var
  test : RIn;

// test procedure 1
procedure test1;
begin
  test.GetChild().SetValue('test...');
end;

// test procedure 2
procedure test2;
begin
  ShowMessage(   test.GetChild().AsString    );    <----- Error!! child interface is already released..
end;
```

Comment: You need to show the code for TIn.GetChild. I am guessing that returns TIn.FChild and that was never created and is nil. There seems to be a lot of confusing parts of this code. You may want to describe what you are trying to do to get a better answer. Putting an interface in a record with the same functions is just asking for trouble.

Comment: function TIn.GetChild() : IIn; begin if FChild = nil then FChild := TIn.Create(); Result := FChild; end; <== ? I Wrote this code....

Comment: Looks like Delphi 2009 bug; probably buggy finalization code in `test1`. Can't say more, need time to debug.

Comment: Code works in Delphi-XE2.

Answer (score 7):

It is Delphi 2009 reference counting bug. I modified your code a little to output reference counters:

```
program Bug2009;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  IIn = interface
    procedure SetValue(v : string);
    function AsString() : string;
    function GetChild() : IIn;
  end;

  RIn = record
    FIn : IIn;

    procedure SetInterface(intf : IIn);
    procedure SetValue(v : string);
    function AsString() : string;
    function GetChild() : RIn;
  end;

  TIn = class(TInterfacedObject, IIn)
  private
    FChild : IIn;
    FValue : string;
  public
    procedure SetValue(v : string);
    function AsString() : string;
    function GetChild() : IIn;
  end;

procedure RIn.SetInterface(intf : IIn);
begin
  FIn := intf;
end;

function RIn.GetChild() : RIn;
var
  childInterface : IIn;
begin
  if FIn = nil then FIn := TIn.Create();
  childInterface := FIn.GetChild();
  Result.SetInterface( childInterface );
end;

procedure RIn.SetValue(v : string);
begin
  if FIn = nil then FIn := TIn.Create();
  FIn.SetValue(v);
end;

function RIn.AsString() : string;
begin
  if FIn = nil then FIn := TIn.Create();

  Result := FIn.AsString();
end;

procedure TIn.SetValue(v : string);
begin
  FValue := v;
end;

function TIn.AsString() : string;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;

function TIn.GetChild() : IIn;
begin
  if FChild = nil then FChild := TIn.Create();
    Writeln(FChild._AddRef - 1);
    FChild._Release;
  Result := FChild;
end;

// global var
var
  test : RIn;

// test procedure 1
procedure test1;
begin
  test.GetChild().SetValue('test...');
end;

// test procedure 2
procedure test2;
begin
  Writeln(   test.GetChild().AsString    );   // <----- Error!! child interface is already released..
end;

begin
  try
    test1;
    test2;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

The output (Delphi 2009) is

[image: Bug2009]

The same test on Delphi XE outputs

[image: No bug Delphi XE]

See different reference counter values

Comment: +1. I think this is a manifestation of http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=90482 Did you verify your code to work in Delphi versions younger than Delphi 2009? Please let us know.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers - have no more Delphi versions at hand, anyone can run the test in my answer and see if it outputs buggy 0 refcounter.

Comment: In Delphi XE, XE2 and XE4 it works fine. Now hopefully someone with Delphi 2010 can check it.